# Trying to run the sql-alchemy tutorial steps. Can't import db from console (ImportError: cannot import name 'db')

Tags: python, import, flask, sqlalchemy

Trying to run the tutorial here: http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/quickstart/ using my app

I have looked at the circular imports problem but I don't think that's it. I'm an absolute beginner to python and flask (and sqlalchemy). My app currently runs, but the database part doesn't

This is the current setup:

```
mysite
|- __init__.py
|- flask_app.py
|- models.py
|- views.py
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

flask_app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, url_for
import random

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql:// -- database uri --'
... app continues here
```

models.py

```
from app import app
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Foo(db.Model):
... model continues here
```

views.py

```
from app import app,models

... views continue here, still not using anything from models
```

when I run `from mysite import db` in the python console I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'db'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your `db` object in *__init__.py*. The stuff that is declared in *__init__.py* defines what can be imported under *mysite/*.

See: [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Also consider moving to the application factory pattern.

For example in *__init__.py*:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
  app = Flask(__name__)
  app.config['DEBUG'] = True
  ... more application config ...

  db.init_app(app)

  return app
```

Then in *flask_app.py*:

```
from mysite import create_app, db

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

I point this out because you instantiate the `app` object twice in the code you've shown. Which is definitely wrong.

Comment: Thanks!! That solved it and let me import db in console
Doesn't SQLAlchemy need the app as an argument though? The app is still working, but I haven't gone round to using  the database yet though.

Comment: My mistake, I forget something important. `db.init_app(app)`. Which sets up the `app` instance for Flask-SQLAlchemy.